# How to generate list of random numbers in Python with some None values?

Tags: python, random

Can I generate a list of random numbers in Python with a mix of 'None' values?

e.g.

```
randomList = [10, 22, 1, None, 98, 43, None ]
```

or

```
randomList = [10, 22, 1, , 98, 43, , 49 ]
```

Comment: FYI your second example is not syntactically valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function to return `None` with a specified probability, else a random integer within a specified range.  Then call it a number of times to make a list.

```
import random

def get_random_number(minval, maxval, none_probability):
    if random.random() < none_probability:
        return None
    else:
        return random.randint(minval, maxval)

def get_random_list(length, minval, maxval, none_probability):
    return [get_random_number(minval, maxval, none_probability)
            for _ in range(length)]

    
print(get_random_list(20, 0, 100, 0.2))
```

Gives:

```
[72, 33, 3, 70, None, 75, 49, 89, 100, 25, None, 55, 85, 95, 75, 9, None, 37, 37, None]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an empty list, then append however many values you need to it by changing 'length'. You can change the approximate ratio of None values to integers by changing 'a' and 'b' respectively.

```
import random as rand

random_list = []
length = 0
a = -20
b = 20

while length < 10:
    number = rand.randint(a,b)
    if number > 0:
        random_list.append(number)
    else:
        random_list.append(None)
    k += 1


print(random_list)
```

Comment: When the number is negative, it take in None as the value. However, there is no specific ask to ensure that the negative numbers should not be part of the list.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. To be even more helpful, please explain how your solution addresses the question. For example, I can tell that your solution could be tweaked by changing some of the numbers it uses (like -10 and 20). One way to provide more information would be to make those into variables and add comments explaining what the variables do. Or you might want to just write a few sentences of introductory material explaining the general idea of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a list of random numbers, then replace certain numbers with `None`. For example, let's use 0 to 9, and replace 0 and 1 with None:

```
import random

r = random.choices(range(10), k=10)   # Get list of numbers
print('Before:', r)
r[:] = [x if x not in range(2) else None for x in r]  # Replace 0-1 with None
print('After:', r)
```

Example run:

```
Before: [0, 1, 4, 6, 2, 9, 0, 6, 9, 5]
After: [None, None, 4, 6, 2, 9, None, 6, 9, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes like this

```
from random import randint as r
randomlist=[r(0, 100) if r(0,100)>r(0,100) else None for i in range(15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def random_list(amount, minval, maxval, none_rate):
    from random import choice
    from numpy import linspace
    arr = linspace(minval, maxval, amount)
    none_count = round(float(amount * none_rate))
    rep = []
    col = [d for d in range(amount)]
    while none_count > 0:
        gen = choice(col)
        if gen not in rep:
            arr[gen] = None
            none_count -= 1
            rep.append(gen)
    return arr


print(random_list(10, 0, 100, 0.3))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for-loop for this and specify where you want to have none cases.
An example of how you can think of it is this:

```
for row_position in range(1, row):
            for col_position in range(1, col):
                self.map = np.concatenate(
                    [[row_position], [col_position]])  # Concatenate the index from row and col together to get indices
                if row_position == col_position:
                    self.slots[row_position][col_position] = None
                else:
                    ...
```